# Standalone updates fail on Windows 10 1709 - "the update is not applicable to your computer"

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1709

I'm trying to install updates on a Windows 10 Pro 1709 PC using standalone updaters  downloaded from the Microsoft Update Catalog.

I'm trying to install on a Windows 10 Pro 1709 system, build 16299.15.

The error message displayed by the Standalone Updater is "The update is not applicable to your computer".

I've worked through [Microsoft's troubleshooting guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-troubleshooting#the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer), which is the basis for most of the SEO-bait articles which Google finds on this subject:

- When I started, there were no updates of any kind installed on the machine. So the updates are definitely not superseded by existing patches!
- The updates are likewise definitely not installed
- I have downloaded the correct architecture (x64)
- I have downloaded patches for the correct Windows major version (1709)
- When it comes to prerequisites, some of the failed updates are Servicing Stack updates. The MS update catalog says Servicing Stack updates don't have prerequisites. Since the other updates were failing, I tried installing the Servicing Stack updates in order anyway. More info on the results of that below.
- I have rebooted the computer many times.
- I have tried using `dism.exe /restorehealth`
- I have run `sfc /scannow` integrity check, which reported that there were no integrity problems.

I was able to successfully install the following Servicing Stack updates, which went smoothly:

- 2019-02 KB4485448
- 2019-05 KB4500641
- 2019-07 KB4509093

However, the two later Servicing Stack updates claim they are "not applicable":

- 2019-09 KB4512575
- 2019-10 KB4521860

After installing the Servicing Stack updates up to 2019-07, I thought I'd try installing the `2019-07 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 KB4507465`, since that *should* work with the Servicing Stack from the same month. That also claims to be "not applicable".

I've also tried the `2019-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 KB4520006`, which is "not applicable". And the `2019-10 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 4.8 for Windows 10 1709 for x64 (KB4519564)`, and the `2019-06 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64 (KB4502562)`, which both also claim to be "not applicable".

So the machine won't accept any of the recent updates that I've tried to install. What else can I do to diagnose the cause of the failed updates?

Comment: They may have been superseded by a newer version of the update, that is why windows updates built into W10 figures this out and only downloads applicable updates.

Comment: This question is about standalone update installers from https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx that have been  copied across to the target computer via USB drives. Some of the updates I’m trying to install are the very latest published this month, so I know they’re not superseded.

Comment: I get that, but who chooses the updates, they may not apply for so many reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to install updates on a Windows 10 Pro 1709 PC using standalone updaters downloaded from the Microsoft Update Catalog.  I'm trying to install on a Windows 10 Pro 1709 system, build 16299.15

The problem you are running into is that the Windows Update catalog does not contain the required updates necessary to update your installation if you are indeed running 16299.15.    Even if you are running 16299.1268, any update released after April 9th, 2019, does not apply to your installation.

> So, the machine won't accept any of the recent updates that I've tried to install. What else can I do to diagnose the cause of the failed updates?

Any update released after April 9th, 2019, for `Windows 10 version 1709` can only be installed on (Windows 10 Enterprise, Windows 10 Education, and IoT Enterprise) version 1709.  The reason you are being told `KB4520006` not applicable to your installation is due to the fact you are not running a supported edition of Windows.

The last delta update that can be installed on your system would be [KB4507455](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4507455%20).  Any update after April 9th, 2019, on the Windows Update Catalog, is an express update which can only be installed on supported editions of Windows 10 version 1709.

Source: [Windows 10 quality updates explained and the end of delta updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/Windows-10-quality-updates-explained-and-the-end-of-delta/ba-p/214426)

> After installing the Servicing Stack updates up to 2019-07, I thought
>   I'd try installing the 2019-07 Cumulative Update for Windows 10
>   KB4507465, since that should work with the Servicing Stack from the
>   same month. That also claims to be "not applicable."

The Servicing Stack updates only allows your installation to receive updates through Windows Update, WSUS, or System Center Configuration Manger.  You were able to install [KB4509093](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4509093) due to the fact it was released before April 9th, 2019.

> So, the machine won't accept any of the recent updates that I've tried to install. What else can I do to diagnose the cause of the failed updates?

You can upgrade your installation to Windows 10 Enterprise, of course even **Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709**, will stop receiving updates on April 9th, 2020.  On April 10th, 2020, Microsoft will no longer release security and quality updates for Windows 10 version 1709.

You can try and install KB4507455 and then attempt to install a cumulative update released after April 9th, 2019.  However, I ran into the same problem with a VM that was running Windows 10 version 1507.  I was unable to even download updates for that version from the catalog, since the updates, did not even exist.  **Even direct links to the update themselves did not work.**

Comment: Ah, I see. The updates I had downloaded were full cumulative updates, rather than express or delta versions, but I hadn’t realised that they are only applicable to 1709 LTSB and not regular 1709 were no longer supported, since the Update Catalog doesn’t distinguish between the two editions of 1709. Would be nice if MS included “Out of support” in their list of causes in the troubleshooting guide! I think we’ll be nuking the whole machine and installing LTSC on it now.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum Microsoft does distinguish between LTSC and Windows 10.  There isn’t a LTSC version for 1709.  Microsoft leaves it to the Administrator to manually download applicable updates from the Catalog

Comment: Well, now I’m even more confused. I searched the catalog for “Windows 10 Cumulative Update 1709 x64”; there is a download listed; I downloaded it; and it’s not applicable. If there’s no LTS version of 1709 to which this update CAN be applied, I’m really not clear on what this 1GB installer is actually for! I accept that 1709 is out of support but I am now very confused about what the recent updates listed in the Update Catalog for 1709 actually are.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709 and/or Windows 10 Education version 1709.  Please note the fact come April 9th 2020 no security updates will be released for version 1709

Comment: For example, this update: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=463c52ee-fd6e-4fba-a709-5f04adee47e1

Comment: @Hydrargyrum If you were running Windows 10 Enterprise/Education version 1709 you would be able to install that specific update

Answer (score 0):

*Assalamu Walikum*

Officially, if you are running Win 10 pro 1709, you are still able to install ["2019-05 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for (****) Systems (KB4499147)"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/may-28-2019-kb4499147-os-build-16299-1182-83457311-6c9f-8d25-928a-90d707714ff1) in your Win 10 1709 HOME/PRO...
But Windows Updater will not give it to you automatically. You have to Manually install its msu installer version

OS Build 16299.1182
[Download from HERE](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4499147)

...............................................................

[Reminder:-](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/may-28-2019-kb4499147-os-build-16299-1182-83457311-6c9f-8d25-928a-90d707714ff1) March 12th and April 9th will be the last two Delta updates for Windows 10, version 1709. Security and quality updates will continue to be available via the express and full cumulative update packages. For more information on this change please visit our blog.

[Reminder:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/may-28-2019-kb4499147-os-build-16299-1182-83457311-6c9f-8d25-928a-90d707714ff1) Windows 10, version 1709, will reach end of service on April 9, 2019 for devices running Windows 10 Home, Pro, Pro for Workstation, and IoT Core editions. These devices will no longer receive monthly security and quality updates that contain protection from the latest security threats. To continue receiving security and quality updates, Microsoft recommends updating to the latest version of Windows 1

### TRICK

**(Unofficial Method)**

In this method you will be able to install The Latest Update (during my posting time) "2020-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for **-based Systems (KB4580328)" in your win 10 HOME/ PRO.... which is Officially only for Win10 1709 Enterprise version licence.

****Step 1:-**
Download the Latest Update's .msu installer file from [Here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4580328)**
OS Build 16299.2166(Officially only for Enterprise)

**Step 2:-**
make a file and copy this code and save the file as file.bat

```
@echo off
Rem Hassan Uddin[EXT] 2021 jully

 call :isAdmin

 if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    goto :run
 ) else (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto :UACPrompt
 )

 exit /b

 :isAdmin
    fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% >nul
 exit /b

 :run
 set input-fileDir="%~f1"
set input-path="%~dp1b"
set file="%~n1.cab"
set "k=%input-path%\"
if not exist %input-path% mkdir %input-path%
Expand -F:* %input-fileDir% %input-path%
SET VAR=
FOR /F %%I IN ('dir %k%*Windows10*.cab /s /b') DO CALL %0 %%I
SET VAR
SET VAR=%VAR%%1
DISM.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:%VAR%
  
 exit /b

 :UACPrompt
   echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %~1", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

   "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
  exit /B`
```

**Step 4:-** now drag and drop the .msu file just on the .bat file(Holding right button)

**Step 5:-** sorry, no more steps available. Enjoy after restart :)

**Picture 1:**
[image: PIC_1]

**Picture 2**
[image: PIC_2]